# Calling a virtual function of a union data member through a pointer results in a segmentation fault

Tags: c++, c++11

I have an instance of a class that I'm storing in a union. When I call a virtual function of the class through a pointer to the union member, I get a segmentation fault. I suspected that my code might not work but to what things (e.g. part of the standard or something similar) should I pay attention in this situation? I tested with Clang++ 3.9.0 and GCC 7.2.0 in C++11 mode.

```
#include <iostream>

struct test_class
{
    virtual void virtual_do_stuff()
    {
        std::cerr << "Doing stuff (virtual)." << std::endl;
    }

    void non_virtual_do_stuff()
    {
        std::cerr << "Doing stuff (non-virtual)." << std::endl;
    }
};


union un
{
    int a;        // Dummy.
    test_class c;

    ~un() {}
    un() {}
};


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    un u;

    test_class c;
    test_class *cptr(&c);
    cptr->virtual_do_stuff();

    u.c = std::move(c);
    u.c.virtual_do_stuff();

    test_class *cptr2(&u.c);
    cptr2->non_virtual_do_stuff();
    cptr2->virtual_do_stuff();      // Causes the segmentation fault.

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you've hit _undefined behavior_ somewhere for me (likely to occur with `union`)..

Comment: member c is not trivial, therefore it must be constructed before using it. Add `new (&u.c) test_class;` before moving. I will post an answer referring to standard later, unless somebody will do it first (which they are welcome to do).

Comment: Non-POD union members have many tedious rules one needs to follow, in order to be type-safe. This is not type-safe, hence the undefined behavior. The short answer: don't put non-PODs into unions. Or, with C++17, use `std::variant` that forces you to implement a union/variant in a type-safe manner.